# Strange 'Permission Denied' message when browsing to CiviCRM home page

Tags: permissions

On a site I've been working on for several years, when I log in to the site, I find that when I browse to the CiviCRM home page /civicrm?reset=1 I get a weird message: "Permission Denied: You do not have permission to view this contact record. Contact the site administrator if you need assistance."

If I simply ignore it and carry on then all seems fine. In the error log I see the following lines:

```
[Tue Jan 26 10:46:17 2016] [error] [client 81.95.52.80] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/sites/default/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.b94a921de7121c494a80645638b20a34.log
[Tue Jan 26 10:46:17 2016] [error] [client 81.95.52.80] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/sites/default/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/delete-this-VJYWu2ovE4
[Tue Jan 26 10:46:17 2016] [error] [client 81.95.52.80] client denied by server configuration: /home/mysite/sites/default/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom/delete-this-uYgWNHRSxL
[Tue Jan 26 10:46:17 2016] [error] [client 81.95.52.80] Attempt to serve directory: /home/mysite/sites/default/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/
```

The files mentioned in the second and third lines above don't exist.

If anyone has any advice about how to tackle this I'd be grateful.

EDIT: [CRM-18300: "Permission denied" message re contact on CiviCRM dashboard](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18300)

Comment: Is this in Drupal? Try rebuilding the permissions from the Drupal status report.

Comment: @liblogger The site uses Drupal, but the message only appears when I first hit a CiviCRM page as a logged in user, and is an error message generated by CiviCRM.

Comment: Drupal has permission settings for CiviCRM, even if you're actually using ACLs to control access, which will prompt CiviCRM to generate relevant error messages- or irrelevant, in this case. I know I've had the same experience (error message but still able to access everything), and this was a possible solution - I'm not adding this as answer because it was a while ago and I don't remember if this worked or if it just went away a while.

Comment: Have you had any success with this error Graham?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It doesn't seem to be causing any problems other than the appearance of the error message when I first log in and go the CiviCRM home page, so I've chosen to ignore it for now. However, I remain keen to resolve it.

Comment: I am seeing the same error messages that Graham is asking about. Another possible clue to this is that we have people using CiviCRM to register for an event. Part of the process sends them out to PayPal to submit a payment. PayPal then sends a IPN message back to CiviCRM so that the registration can be shown as paid. However even though PayPal shows that the IPN messages were sent successfully the registration status is not being updated. Since these log messages are related to the Contribute module I wonder if these might be related?

Comment: Something else that is interesting in our case is that the client IP address that is shown in the error log is the IP address of the web server where CiviCRM is installed.

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, and answers should only be used to address the original question directly. Once you have earned sufficient site reputation, you can leave a comment such as this one for clarifications. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: i used to see this regularly on a 4.4.x site - which started its life back in 1.4 i think -what version is yours on

Comment: Those error messages in your webserver access log are not symptoms of a problem - they are caused by internal methods requesting those files to check they *aren't* available, eg [`CRM_Utils_Check_Component_Security::checkLogFileIsNotAccessible()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4e3acd4be7b6818781bd26148621519ce36dfe5c/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Security.php#L51).

Comment: I've seen this error message too ... when I log in and visit the CiviCRM dashboard on www.civicrm.org :) If I run into it in an environment where I can debug it, I will.

Comment: Hello, any idea about how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Just a though, but, do you have any dashboard reports that might contain some contacts that have been deleted? Have you tried removing all of your dashboard reports to see if the problem goes away? Basic I know, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

The errors in your log that you note are not a problem, they are CiviCRM doing a little security check for you (and succeeding).

I've seen this occasionally on my servers, and especially on my staging server. I believe that the cause is indirectly related to the errors you are seeing, in that:

1. If you're logged in, CiviCRM does a fair amount of these checks before rendering the page.
2. If you have production-type settings on a not-super-fast server, then you can get timeouts of various flavours that aren't necessarily going to show up in your apache/webserver logs.

As you probably also experience, just reloading the page will solve the issue, presumably because CiviCRM and or the webserver is using some kind of caching so it doesn't take so long.

In my case, extending the default backend timeout in my varnish configuration eliminated the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I don't think this is an answer though. Perhaps better posted as a comment?

Answer (score 2):

I have rarely seen this error display itself when an actual permissions problem has occurred that is preventing work getting done.  Normally it shows up for no good reason that I can tell.  @alandixon may be right that it has something to do with server cache or delay.   I've turned this situation into a positive.

My answer is to use Word Replacements feature under Administer > Customize.

Change "Permission Denied" to "Welcome Back" and the rest of the text to "It's good to see you again."  Civi is now more friendly than ever.

Comment: That brightened my day, thanks. A great example of how to make the best of things!

Comment: I having this error display itself to all users on our donate page. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

A client reported this issue to us recently and after some investigation we found the cause to be the way that particular profiles had been setup.

In short, any active profile with ‘View/Edit Drupal User Account’ option selected AND if you have a group selected in the ‘Limit listings to a specific Group?’ (under advanced setting of the profile) causes this message to appear when you switch from a Drupal page to a CiviCRM page.

This was reproduced on the demo site today (23rd April 2020).

Solution to resolve this issue for the client was to remove the group from the ‘Limit listings to a specific Group?’ option under advanced settings of the profile as this was not required.

[image]

Comment: good sleuthing!